# JSTL foreach not working. Can't get list from class?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

My class:

```
@WebListener
public class Navbar implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        List<NavItem> navItems = new ArrayList<>();
        navItems.add(new NavItem("/index.jsp", "Startseite", NavItem.Alignment.LEFT, ""));
        navItems.add(new NavItem("/login.jsp", "Login", NavItem.Alignment.LEFT, ""));
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("navItems", navItems);
    }
}
```

My jsp file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach var="item" items="${navItems}">
    <c:out value="${item.name}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

How can I access the "navItems" from my jsp file? Do I have to copy my java files into "WEB-INF"? I'm  using maven with Intellij. I also  searched on google but found nothing useful. Please help me.

Comment: *Do I have to copy my java files into WEB-INF* - are you meaning that your class files are **not** below WEB-INF?

Comment: No they are not. I dunno where the compiled class files are.

Comment: me neither.....

Comment: Do you have jar file in pom.xml or in lib folder?